# Aligning lists in Emacs org-mode with a proportional font?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Does org-mode have a way to correctly align numbered lists (and other indented items) when using a proportional font, like Helvetica?

Thanks!

Comment: Emacs isn't really a word processor so what you describe would be really difficult. For a proportional font the columns for two lines of different text don't necessarily line up. In order to have the functionality you describe Emacs would need a Ruler that measured the page seperately from the columns of the text. I'm not aware of any Emacs plugin that will do this and I'm dangerously close to being nerd sniped so I'm going to stop typing now.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full fix, but I use the following in my init.el:

```
   ;; Ensure the indent face is always fixed pitch. This matches my
   ;; headline font, and therefore we indent consistent with heading font
   ;; pitch.
   (add-hook 'after-init-hook
       (lambda ()
           (set-face-attribute 'org-indent nil :inherit 'fixed-pitch)))
```

This gets the left-hand edge of indents working for me (so they match the indent of headings, for example), but isn't quite right if the bullet/list line is sufficiently long to wrap. Still, it fixes the main problem for me which was these items appearing to be at a higher level than the headings.